# Need Spring Boot to redirect to https behind F5 BigIP SSL Proxy but listen on http

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, f5

How do I continue to listen on port 80 (http) but send a 302 redirect to port 443 (https) in a Spring Boot app for the login page. I need this because my application is behind a F5 BigIP proxy that terminates the SSL certificate and sends http requests to my application and currently, I am seeing this behaviour:

This is the current **flawed flow**:

1. Client requests https://myapp.example.com
2. F5 BigIP translates to (HTTP)myapp.example.com
3. my Spring Boot application redirects to (HTTP)myapp.example.com/login as a 302 directive to the     client
4. Client requests (**HTTP**)myapp.example.com/login
5. F5 BigIP rejects HTTP request

   **Wanted flow:**
6. my Spring Boot application sends a redirect to (HTTPS)myapp.example.com/login as a 302 to the   client (Location=(HTTPS)myapp.example.com/login)
7. F5 BigIP translates to (HTTP)myapp.example.com/login
8. my Spring boot application responds with the login page and everything is Honky Dory

I am using Spring Boot version 1.2.8 and my application is behind a F5 BigIp load balancer.  The BigIP terminates the SSL certificate and redirects all HTTPS requests to the Spring Boot application listening ONLY on port 80 (http).

```
@Configuration                                                   
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/error", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/img/**", "/help", "/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().hasAuthority("USER")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login-error")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }
    }
```

I followed the //docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-enable-https documentation adding:

These application.properties:

```
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
server.tomcat.internal-proxies=x\.x\.x\.x|x\.x\.x\.x  (I tested without this parameter as well)
```

BTW: Forcing HTTPS with http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure(); does not work in this case, because I need the second request coming from the F5 BigIp on HTTP to work, using this setting would loop the whole redirecting dance.

I need to configure my app to redirect a client request https://myApp.example.com that is proxied by BigIP to http://myApp.example.com/
To https://myApp.example.com/login so the F5 BigIP accepts it.

This is the result from a curl request:
curl -L -b -vk --url https://myApp.example.com --verbose -vs > curl-output.txt 2>&1

```
STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x440f160; line 1392 (connection #-5000)
* Rebuilt URL to: https://myApp.example.com/
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITRESOLVE handle 0x440f160; line 1428 (connection #0)
*   Trying XXX.XX.XX.XXX...
…
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x440f160; line 1596 (connection #0)
} [5 bytes data]
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: myApp.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
…
< HTTP/1.1 302 
…
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
* Added cookie JSESSIONID="4CE1A6F2AB684C6E01774E5289AF2AC0" for domain myApp.example.com, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4CE1A6F2AB684C6E01774E5289AF2AC0;path=/;HttpOnly
****< Location: http://myApp.example.com/login <- this needs to be HTTPS****
< Date: Wed, 09 May 2018 22:30:36 GMT
…
* Connection #0 to host myApp.example.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://myApp.example.com/login'  <- this needs to be HTTPS
* STATE: PERFORM => CONNECT handle 0x440f160; line 1949 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 1. The cache now contains 2 members
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITRESOLVE handle 0x440f160; line 1428 (connection #1)
*   Trying XXX.XX.XX.XXX...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* STATE: WAITRESOLVE => WAITCONNECT handle 0x440f160; line 1509 (connection #1)
* connect to XXX.XX.XX.XXX port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to myApp.example.com port 80: Connection refused<= Not the result we want
* Closing connection 1
```

Comment: You said you want to do an HTTPS redirect and then at step 3 you write: "my Spring Boot application redirects to (http)myapp.example.com/login as a 302 directive to the client ". So is your application putting an HTTPS or HTTP link in the Location header of the 302 redirect? You are not showing the part of your code that generates the redirect. You need to fix the URL there.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so fast. I added the snippet to the question.

Comment: Does this (I do not use Spring Boot) really generate a 302 HTTP Redirect with a Location header? It does not look like it, but again, I do not use Spring Boot.

Comment: Yes, it does, you can see it in the curl trace.

Comment: Yes, but the code is not very clear to me (again, not a user of Spring Boot). So it seems the redirection by itself is done by your framework and not yourself, so you may need to learn more about the framework to convince it to do that or something to be able to override it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625699/how-to-redirect-automatically-to-https-with-spring-boot and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655875/spring-boot-redirect-http-to-https

Comment: Thank you, Patrick, I saw those questions but could not find what I was looking for. I edited the flow part that might make my question clearer.

Comment: are you inserting the X-FORWARDED-PROTO header at the BIG-IP with a policy or iRule?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. yes the x-forwarded-proto is in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was never solved on the server side. The systems engineer in charge of the BIG IP changed some configuration settings and now, it's working like they want it to work. I have not asked yet how the Big-IP configuration works. I will post something, if possible, when I find out.